# Creating PDFs from scratch on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, pdf-generation

I was working on creating a pdf receipts on my simple application. I was able to make it work for a generic/mostly hard coded entries. However, when I want the pdf to print out the amounts for a specfic charge (that is not Hard Coded) I get this error on my charges_controller.rb file - "undefined local variable or method `amount' for #" I have listed below my specific github as well the relevant below. Thank you so much for your help guys :)

Exact Error Message:

uninitialized constant Charge::Amount
app/models/charge.rb:18:in `receipt'
app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:64:in`block (2 levels) in show'
app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:60:in `show'

Github - https://github.com/OmarZV/PDF

**charges_controller.rb**

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :set_charge, only: [:show]
def index
@charges = Charge.all
end
def new
@charge = Charge.new
end
def create
@charge = Charge.new(charge_params)
respond_to do |format|
if @charge.save
format.html { redirect_to @charge, notice: 'Charge was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @charge }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @charge.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
def show
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json
    format.pdf {
    send_data @charge.receipt.render,
      filename: "#{@charge.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}-gorails-receipt.pdf",
      type: "application/pdf",
      disposition: :inline
  }
end
end
private
def set_charge
@charge = current_user.charges.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

**charge.rb when it works**

```
class Charge < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
def receipt
Receipts::Receipt.new(
id: id,
  product: "GoRails",
  company: {
    name: "One Month, Inc.",
    address: "37 Great Jones\nFloor 2\nNew York City, NY 10012",
    email: "teachers@onemonth.com",

  },
  line_items: [
    ["Date",           created_at.to_s],
    ["Account Billed", "(#{user.email})"],
    ["Product",        "GoRails"],
    ["Amount",         "Amount"],
    ["Charged to",     "{Card_type}"],

  ]      
)
end
end
```

**charge.rb when it doesn't works**

```
class Charge < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
def receipt
Receipts::Receipt.new(
id: id,
  product: "GoRails",
  company: {
    name: "One Month, Inc.",
    address: "37 Great Jones\nFloor 2\nNew York City, NY 10012",
    email: "teachers@onemonth.com",

  },
  line_items: [
    ["Date",           created_at.to_s],
    ["Account Billed", "(#{user.email})"],
    ["Product",        "GoRails"],
    ["Amount",         "$#{Amount / 100}.00"],
    ["Charged to",     "#{Card_type} (**** **** **** #{Card_last4})"],

  ]      
)
end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
has_many :charges
end
```

Comment: Please take a look at [Posting Good Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which has detailed and useful instructions to help us help you. What line is the error referring to? Please post the full error, you cut it off too soon. Please format your code as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you haven't posted the part of your code where the error is originating from. Can you please post the original error, including which file it is coming from?\

Comment: max and Tyler thank you so much for your comments, my apologies for the way the question was presented. I've just put in the full original error message as well as the charge.rb (when it works and gives me a pdf) and a charge.rb (that I want but gives me an error). Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a capital `Amount` in your model which will reference a constant. It should be lowercase `amount` to use the attribute on the charge record instead.

I think that should be: `["Amount",         "$#{amount / 100}.00"]`

Comment: This works perfectly :)  I had generated a scaffold with my attributes capitalized when they should always be lower case.